# Http trigger azure function deployment in kubernetes using KEDA wihtout exposing using ingress control

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, keda

I created an azure function and its docker images is deployed in Kubernetes.This function  should work internally in Kubernetes. I don't want to expose my function to out side world. How do i scale the azure function without ingress control.Is it possible ?. I saw the below link,that scale the azure function using ingress control.
[Keda](http://https:/https://dev.to/anirudhgarg_99/scale-up-and-down-a-http-triggered-function-app-in-kubernetes-using-keda-4m42).
I just want to use the azure function internally.

Comment: Did you figure it out / Are you still looking for an answer?  What kind of service is it (httptrigger, servicebus, ...)? Keda needs to know the statistics of your service so that it can scale up or down if needed.